# problems with QVariantMap("No source available for "QBasicAtomicInt_fetchAndAddOrdered()")

Tags: c++, qt, blackberry-10

I am getting this error (colored in red):

"**No source available for "QBasicAtomicInt_fetchAndAddOrdered() at 0xba49e3f0**" - when I try to execute following line in debug mode:

> item.mediaUrl =  results.value("itemMediaUrl").toString();

where *results* is a *QVariantMap* (I manage to successfully read other values from *results*, e.g., other strings, ints, etc.) and *item* is just an object which has a variable of type *QString, mediaUrl*.

Any help?? Any suggestions?? Thanks

ps. It seems I fixed it in this way:

```
QUrl url =  results.value("itemMediaUrl").toUrl();
    item.mediaUrl = url.toString();
```

I think if you put the two lines in one (i.e., directly apply toString() after toUrl... it may still not work...

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data ?